# Can't use css libraries in my magento2 store

Tags: magento2

I need to use PostCSS with tailwindcss in my magento 2 store, but I cannot import files from node_modules and cannot find information about it. I think that this is impossible. maybe you can help me, ** i need to connect css library via npm to my magento2 **

[this is documentation that i need it](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#installing-tailwind-css-as-a-post-css-plugin)

Comment: Did you find out a solution?